# Cartesian product of 2d and 1d numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2d and 1d numpy and I want to join them with Cartesian product.
For example the numpy's are:

```
td = np.array([[1,2,3],
               [4,5,6],
               [7,8,9]])

od = np.array([1,2,3])
```

The expected result should be:

```
[[1,2,3,1],
 [1,2,3,2],
 [1,2,3,3],
 [4,5,6,1],
 [4,5,6,2],
 [4,5,6,3],
 [7,8,9,1],
 [7,8,9,2],
 [7,8,9,3]]
```

The following code does not achieve the desired result:

```
import numpy as np

rslt = np.transpose([np.tile(td, len(od)), np.repeat(od , len(td))])
```

What needs to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
np.c_[np.repeat(td,3,axis=0),np.tile(od,3).reshape((-1,1))]
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 2],
       [4, 5, 6, 3],
       [7, 8, 9, 1],
       [7, 8, 9, 2],
       [7, 8, 9, 3]])
```